# NavigationView SetCheckedItem does not trigger OnNavigationItemSelected

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

I want to select a specific item in nav drawer when application starts.
I added `navigationView.SetCheckedItem(Resource.Id.nav_gallery);` in visual studio default template.

```
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);
        Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar toolbar = FindViewById<Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);
        SetSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = FindViewById<FloatingActionButton>(Resource.Id.fab);
        fab.Click += FabOnClick;

        DrawerLayout drawer = FindViewById<DrawerLayout>(Resource.Id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar, Resource.String.navigation_drawer_open, Resource.String.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.AddDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.SyncState();

        var navigationView = FindViewById<NavigationView>(Resource.Id.nav_view);
        navigationView.SetNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        navigationView.SetCheckedItem(Resource.Id.nav_gallery);

    }
```

But OnNavigationItemSelected is not called

```
    public bool OnNavigationItemSelected(IMenuItem item)
    {
        int id = item.ItemId;

        if (id == Resource.Id.nav_camera)
        {
            // Handle the camera action
        }
        else if (id == Resource.Id.nav_gallery)
        {

        }
```

If I click the nav items `OnNavigationItemSelected` is called and everything works right.
What is the proper way to select a default item?

UPDATE

I solved it adding this line. The specific item gets clicked.

```
 navigationView.Menu.PerformIdentifierAction(Resource.Id.nav_gallery, 0);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
  navigationView.getMenu().getItem(position).setChecked(true);
```

you can create a function

```
 public void selectDrawerItem(int position, String tag) {

    switch (position) {

        case 0:
            fragment = new DashboardFragment();
            tvToolbarTitleLand.setText("Dashboard");
            break;

         //code.................
    }

    if (fragment != null) {

        FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.enter_from_right, R.anim.exit_to_right);
        transaction.replace(R.id.flMainContainer, fragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(tag);
        transaction.commit();
    }

    navigationView.getMenu().getItem(position).setChecked(true);
```

}

let me know if you have any queries about this.

Answer (score -1):

## select that item programmatically

```
public class BaseApp extends AppCompatActivity {

//define variables

protected String LOGTAG = "LOGDEBUG";

protected Toolbar toolbar;
protected NavigationView navigationView;
protected DrawerLayout drawerLayout;

private DateManager db = null;


@Override


  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);





navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);
```

// set the dashboard at startup

```
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame, new DashboardFragment());
    fragmentTransaction.commit();

    setNavDrawer();
}

//CREATE A NavDrawer() void

private void set NavDrawer(){
toolbar = (toolbar) findViewById(r.i.d.toolbar);

setsupportactionbar(toolbar);

navigationView.setNavigationItemSelected(memuItem)





  {

if (menuItems.isChecked()) menuItem.setChecked(false);



 else menuItem.setChecked(true);

drawerlayout.closeDrawers();


//now checlk which items are being clicked
```

//and performing appropriate action

```
if (menuItem.isChecked()) menuItem.setChecked(false);
            

else menuItem.setChecked(true);


 switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {

 case R.id.home:

                    DashboardFragment dashboardFragment = new DashboardFragment();
                    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame, dashboardFragment,"DASHBOARD_FRAGMENT");
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
                    return true;
```